# Julia - Constrained Optimization

Tags: optimization, julia

I am trying to minimize a function (fairly complicated, no analytical form). 
First, I residualized it and run the following:

```
using Optim
x0= [.1, .3, 1/3, .75]
f(x) = prstream_res(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4])
z= optimize(f, x0)
```

which gives me an unconstrained solution. However, the solution Julia finds has no real world sense (some of the minimizer arguments are negative).

I need to constrain the solution to positive values only. As a matter of fact, I can give a lower and upper bound of resulting parameters.

I tried:

```
f(x) = prstream_res(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4])
lower= [0, 0, 0, 0]
upper= [1, 1, 1, 1]
x0= [.1, .3, 1/3, .75]
inner_optimizer = GradientDescent()
results = optimize(f, lower, upper, x0, Fminbox(inner_optimizer))
```

but it doesn't work throwing

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching optimize(::typeof(f), ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Fminbox{GradientDescent{InitialPrevious{Float64},HagerZhang{Float64,Base.RefValue{Bool}},Nothing,Optim.var"#13#15"},Float64,Optim.var"#43#45"})
```

Can please someone help me constrain the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you perhaps need to supply either the gradient function as the second argument, or provide the keyword `autodiff=:forward`?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to check out [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl).

Comment: You can also use TRON 
```
using ADNLPModels, JSOSolvers
nlp = ADNLPModel(f, x0, lower, upper)
output = tron(nlp)
```